# How to Get AJAX Table Records in Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

How do I display all records in the context of AJAX Laravel when I click the button to display the table be updated and new content.But not work this code for me.

my table:

```
<table class="table table-condensed text-right">
                <thead class="">
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-right">remove</th>
                    <th class="text-right">edit</th>
                    <th class="text-right">name</th>
                    <th class="text-right">#</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($category as $cat)
                    <tr id="append">
                        <td><a id="destroy" href="{{action('categoryController@destroy', [$cat->id])}}"><span
                                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
                        <td><a href="{{action('categoryController@update',[$cat->id])}}"><span
                                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
                        <td><a href="{{action('categoryController@show', [$cat->id])}}">{{$cat->category}}</a>
                        </td>
                        <th class="text-right">{{$cat->id}}</th>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

my controller:

```
public function index2($request)
{
    $category = Category::table($request->all())->get();
    return ['id'=>$category];
}
```

my ajax code:

```
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: '{!! URL::route('index2') !!}',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    }
                })
```

use this code without ajax in controller:

```
    public function index()
{
    $category = Category::all();
    return view('admin.category', compact('category'));
}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: What happen if you try to access the Ajax route directly, without the ajax request?

Comment: Check your laravel log file if there are errors. And what error do you get in the alert. And moreover can you paste the route that the url hit.

Answer (score 2):

you can't use @foreach in this case, because your data are js, take a look in this example https://gist.github.com/triceam/3407134

in my package too
https://github.com/marcosrjjunior/lvlgrid

Comment: This code is good but I do not understand. If you can explain my code